# How important is the ordering of media feature expressions used in media queries, and what, if anything, should be prioritised?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

If, for example, I'm wanting to target a portrait-oriented screen with a minimum width of 500px, would it matter at all which order these are specified in within the query?

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) and (min-width: 500px) { ... }
```

I haven't read through the user agent parts of the CSS specification, but I'm assuming CSS is read left to right, so for the above it would first check the orientation and, if it evaluates to true it would move on to the minimum width. Right? So what if I had it the other way around:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) and (orientation: portrait) { ... }
```

Presumably this would then check the minimum width *before* the orientation. If this is indeed the case, what should I be prioritising here, orientation or width? Or would this something more specific to what other media queries are in use? (Width usage vs orientation usage.)

In a media query with few media features I imagine this is trivial, but what about something much more specific:

```
@media
    print
        and (min-resolution: 300dpi),
    projection
        and (color),
    screen
        and (orientation: landscape)
        and (min-width: 50px) { ... }
```

In this situation, would I be better off (even if marginally) to add `screen` *before* `print` if my content is less likely to be printed?

Comment: Are you talking about somehow leveraging short-circuit evaluation here?

Comment: I'm willing to bet the process happens so fast that the difference is negligible.  Since programs typically process from left to right/top to bottom, there *might* be a slight performance gain by placing most likely matches first.